# using a 9 volt AC 25 va power supply in lieu of a 9 volt AC 2000 milliamp power supply

Tags: power-supply

I have a Line 6 Pod 2 modeling box that needs a 9 volt AC 2000 milliamp power supply. All I can find is a 9 volt AC 25 voltage amp power supply can I use that instead?

Answer (score 1):

the 25 VA power supply can deliver up to 2.77 Amps (2770 mA) so is a suitable replacement for the 2000 mA supply.